# Wagtail CMS how to validate the content of one page before publishing or saving it as draft

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

I am trying to make a page with Wagtail CMS that validates the content whenever I save/publish the page inside the admin editor.

The content that I want to be validated is the content of 3 SnippetChooserPanels from within the page. Basically let's say I have these 3 snippets : SnippetA, SnippetB and SnippetC and these snippets (or Django models because that's what they really are) have the following relationships:

- SnippetA has one to many relationship with SnippetB
- SnippetB has one to many relationship with SnippetC.

When the user saves/publishes the page I want to verify:

- that all the 3 snippet types have been chosen
- that there is a correct relationship between the snippets (ie SnippetC belongs to SnippetB , and SnippetB belongs to SnippetsA, or in other words the 3 snippets are joined together correctly in SQL database terms)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wagtail allows you to customise the editing form for each of your `Page` models via the `base_form_class` attribute on your `Page` model.

The class that this references must be one that subclasses `WagtailAdminPageForm`. This is a Django `Form` at its core and hence has a `clean` method that allows additional custom validation on submission along with failing the save step and providing per field error messages.

##### Docs

- Wagtail - [customising the editing interface](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms)
- Django - [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/)

##### Code Example **models.py**

```py
from django import forms
from django.db import models

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel


class CustomPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        # Make sure that the the snippets relate to each other correctly
        snippet_a = cleaned_data['snippet_a']
        snippet_b = cleaned_data['snippet_b']
        snippet_c = cleaned_data['snippet_c']

        # example validation only - you will need to work this out based on your exact requirements
        if snippet_a.pk is snippet_b.pk:
            self.add_error('snippet_a', 'The snippets must be different')
        if snippet_b.pk is snippet_c.pk:
            self.add_error('snippet_a', 'The snippets must be different')
        if snippet_c.pk is snippet_a.pk:
            self.add_error('snippet_a', 'The snippets must be different')
        if snippet_c.pk is snippet_b.pk:
            self.add_error('snippet_a', 'The snippets must be different')

        return cleaned_data


class EventPage(Page):
    # note: actual models.ForeignKey usage not added, just for the example
    snippet_a = models.ForeignKey()
    snippet_b = models.ForeignKey()
    snippet_c = models.ForeignKey()

    content_panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel('snippet_a'),
        SnippetChooserPanel('snippet_b'),
        SnippetChooserPanel('snippet_c'),
    ]

    base_form_class = CustomPageForm
```

Comment: Yes, it seems it is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Hey LB, is there a reason why it wouldn't work in this case to just override the `clean()` method on the `EventPage` model itself? Is it necessary to use a custom form?

Comment: Hey @ScottCranfill - good point, I guess it could work that way, I just copied/pasted the docs example. I think the docs example was for adding a field also. feel free to edit this answer if you want.